# point giving me errors when drawing rectangle

Tags: c#

```
private Point hLocation;
```

I am stuck on this.  Please help.

> Error 2 The type or namespace name 'Point' could not be found (are you
>   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1):

Didn't you read the exception message? It seems pretty self explanatory:

> are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?

The [`Point`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point.aspx) structure is declared in the `System.Drawing` assembly inside the `System.Drawing` namespace. So make sure that you have referenced this assembly in your project and that you have brought the namespace into scope with a `using` directive:

```
using System.Drawing;
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you must declare your variable with the namespace:

```
    private System.Drawing.Point hLocation;
```

Or you must include the namespace above your class declaration:

```
    using System.Drawing;
```

The second way is better since you will likely be using the Point type more than once in your class.  Having to reference it as System.Drawing.Point over and over again will be redundant.