# C# rectangle object

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and i have run into this problem, I am trying to create a Rectangle object in C# using this syntax

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Rectangle myRectangle = new Rectangle(20, 20, 250, 200);
    }
```

but it gives me the error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'Rectangle' could not be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)    
ConsoleApplication15
```

Comment: Well, you're missing a using directive or an assembly reference.

Comment: Which part of the error message are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: Rectangle is a structure so there won't be a real `Rectangle object` but more or less just for numbers even after including the Drawing namespace

Comment: Possible duplicate of [point giving me errors when drawing rectangle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11240488/point-giving-me-errors-when-drawing-rectangle). Close enough to lead you to the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use Visual Studio and it does not directly work

add it **Project>Add Reference...**
(the forth from the bottom)

https://puu.sh/oMXmx/10e6c9e66e.png

Answer (score 1):

You need to import the namespace of whichever `Rectangle` you want.

Put the appropriate line at the top of your file.

```
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
```

[MSDN System.Drawing.Rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

[MSDN System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: i tried to do that as well but that didnt work, using System.Drawing does nothing and System.Windows.Shapes creates an error -- The type or namespace name 'Shapes' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference)

Answer (score 0):

`System.Drawing` is the namespace you want for rectangles. 
[msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.rectangle(v=vs.110).aspx)

You need to add an assembly reference to use stuff in the system.drawing namespace. 

[Here is how you add a ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx)

[Here ishow to draw a rectangle.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwi7-ODp8s_MAhXMFh4KHX8jDDcQFggcMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fztxk24yx(v%3Dvs.110).aspx&usg=AFQjCNEbg0qa1UYN4x-cZGRSMFOF-fSkkQ&sig2=hJnhVocBsKEh1v3IwT4Xqw&bvm=bv.121658157,d.dmo&cad=rja)